# a specific word for a set of subjects other than the major you're studying for

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Here in the Netherlands we have a period during our bachelors in which we can chose a different (though related) field of study, we call this period (which is usually half a year) A "Minor".

For example I studied computer engineering (which is my major, if i understand it correctly) then during these 4 years I spend half a year studying Information System Security, this half year is the Minor.

In the English language, is this also called a Minor? Is this a thing people/companies will understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nouns/verbs "major" and "minor", for the primary and secondary subjects at university, are more common in the USA than in the UK, but even in the UK they are understood, especially by people working in Human Resources (who read CVs).  I'm not sure about other places.  I think that if you said

> "I majored in Computer Engineering and minored in Information System Security"

then anyone who's job it is to read CVs/Resumes will know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're studying is directly relevant to your major, it is referred to as *sub-major*.

> My major is Robotics Engineering with a sub-major in Artificial Intelligence

A minor would be branch that isn't directly related to your major it's referred to as a *minor*:

> My major is Engineering with a minor in Human Resources